# javaFx Image Height and Width got backwards?

Tags: java, image, javafx, png

I am making a game in javaFx. The way entities in my game is rendered is dependent on one of their fields called "angle", like this:

```
        gc.save();
        gc.transform(new Affine(new Rotate(angle, getCenterX(), getCenterY())));
        gc.drawImage(image, x, y);
        gc.restore();
```

"Gc" is the GraphicsContext. The getCenter methods will use the height and width of the images. However, the images are not rendered properly. I ran some tests and found that when I use the **get Width** method, it actually returns the height of the image. When I call the **get Height** method, it returns the width. My guess is that it's because the png images I use have been rotated 90 degrees in respect to their original state. However, when I go to preview and look at their size, it seems that everything is fine. I tried duplicating the images, but it doesn't really work. Any ideas how to fix this? I don't have a verifiable code example because I believe this question is more related to properties of png files and javaFx's Image methods than my program's logic.
[image]
[image]

---

Here is the verifiable code example:

```
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class TestImage {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Image BLUE01 = new Image("/blue01.png");
        System.out.println("height : "+ BLUE01.getHeight());
        System.out.println("wdith : "+ BLUE01.getWidth());
    }
}
```

---

And here is the image:
[image]

Comment: where is the method definition of image.getWidth()?

Comment: @Aaron It's a javaFx method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume `getWidth` goes through the current graphic context as well? If you remove the line that rotates, does it work correctly?

Comment: @usr2564301 I created my Image as public static final, so it should not be affected by the GraphicsContext in any way...

Comment: Did you check immediately after creating the `Image` object (assuming you do not load it asynchronously)? I've never observed this kind of behavior so my guess would be that you've use the wrong image or that there is another error in the code.

Comment: Indulge me, I won't hold it against you if it does not work. Remove the transform line and see what happens. Best scenario is that it then works, and your assumption is wrong. Worse is if it does not, because then you need to show a lot more code.

Comment: @usr2564301 I removed the transformation line, but it seems that the getHeight and getWidth method still return numbers different from the ones I see in Preview... And I'm sure I'm not using the wrong image because I only have 3 images, which are all 16*16 in the resource folder, while the program prints 18 and 20 as width and height...

Comment: @fabian I integrated what I wanted to say to you into the comment above

Comment: If you want better help, you are going to need to do [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sedrick I just did

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem comes from not my code but my use of IDE... It turns out that after I edit or add image in my resource folder, I need to click "refresh" in eclipse...